# pass data to dialog via GET on windows.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So, i'm loading a page in a separate jquery ui dialog, on which i pass a value via get, but when consulting the `window.location` variable, i'm getting the location of the parent page, and not the one i'm loading. How can i solve this?

Comment: Post some code and/or a working sample on JSFiddle.

Comment: Exactly what location are you trying to get? The one you are currently watching or the one in the dialog?

Comment: my mistake, i got it wrong, i was indeed receiving a location, but it is the parent page, not from the page i'm loading

Comment: So, i found out a work around

Instead of loading the page, i set a iframe to load the page, but still, i'd like to know if there's a way to achieve this via the `load` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top.location.href` this will retrieve the url that your browser is using.

Comment: my mistake, i got it wrong, i was indeed receiving a location, but it is the parent page, not from the page i'm loading